# How to prevent hibernate to load lines

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently running in a case where I might reach my limits.

I'm using Java with Hibernate3 for ORMapping. As I'm developping on legacy code, refactoring is not possible that easily. In particular optional entities I'm talking about may have been developped with inheritence, but today it's not just the case.

I have a RootEntity (R) having 2 optional entities (A) and (B). At least one entity would be a child of the root entity:

`(A) <---(R)---> (B)`

My configuration file forces the collection to be eagerly loaded, criteria defines aliases. I end up having a very long query that ***DOES*** load all the lines with all the necessary elements:

 `(R) cols ... (A) cols ... (B) cols ...`

I went to debug mode with Hibernate sources and Hydration would correctly construct (R), (A) or (B) when found.

***Problem***: After hydration phase, Hibernate won't be able to find one of the entity. If A has been loaded, it would try to load B; if B has been loaded, it would try to load A.

This would result as an optional query for each line that:
- may not retrieve any row 
- may retrieve some unecessary row (foreign key ID would have some correspondance, but this would not be used in the application)

***Question***: How would it be possible to tell Hibernate "based on the row and the type of (R) ignore loading of unwanted entity *(either (A) or (B)*)" ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only approach I can think of would be to make the load lazy and to force it yourself in a `@PostLoad` method on `R`.

Comment: This sounds reasonable, but my primary goal is to load everything in 1 query, thus avoiding non-necessary load over DB. In any way number of query with such solution wouldn't be higher than current solution.

Comment: Have you considered using @DiscriminatorColumn to differentiate the A from B?